# How do use FME Workbench to convert MVT Tileset to GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, fme-form, vector-tiles

I have tried to use FME Workbench to convert MVT Tilesets to Geojson and I have had some issues. I have followed the guidelines in the link below. https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/mvt/mvt.htm

I have saved MVT files in this format

```
c:/3006/zoomlevel(z)/tilecol(x)/tilerow(y).mvt
```

And when I try to read the files as MVT Tileset and translating into Geojson I cannot get it to work, not sure what I am doing wrong. The attached link includes the files Zipped and the Workspace I have been using to perform the operation.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MAz4R4f6ozO7rb_VytLCHg938dg4f1a4?usp=sharing

I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the tiles you have downloaded are local. The bottom left corner is 0,0. So you need to georeference the tiles to real world coordinates. This can be done easily with the Offsetter transformer, if you have the real world coordinates for each tile.

I think this can be done when you have the original tilematrix for the corresponding zoomlevel. So you need to obtain or reproduce the tilematrix and then merge the real world bounding box coordinates from the tiles to you files based on column and row number.

I tried to reproduce the tilematrix for level 10 with the information you supplied on the forumpost (see below) but I ran out of time to finish it properly. Please note the CRS is epsg:3006 (SWEREF99 TM).

```
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>14285.71428571428623399697</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>8500000.000000 -1200000.000000</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>4096</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>4096</MatrixHeight>
```